# Novice looking for help with a current sensor circuit

Tags: current, sensor, detector, non-contact

I'm an electronics novice trying to figure out how to detect when current is flowing to certain tools in my shop so I can add some automation to my dust collection system.

I essentially want to build my own version of the detection mechanism in [this](https://www.ivacswitch.com/ivac-pro-auto-sensor/) so I can control a relay, and hopefully for a lot less than $70 per tool. As you can see, it simply clamps onto the cord. Then you "calibrate" it by sliding it up and down the wire until the LED illuminates. There's also a pot for adjusting sensitivity.

I have spent countless hours reading about various current sensors that employ either a split or solid core transformer. Everything I've found says I need to isolate only one of the conductors, but I don't want to cut the power cords on my tools or create a pass-through plug-in device.

I've found scores of videos for creating a non-contact voltage detector using an antenna, but nothing that would tell me when current is flowing.

After days of searching, I can't figure out.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Follow-up:
So I think I may have found what I was looking for in one of the "Related" links; I guess I wasn't searching for the right words before. Anyway, it looks like [this device](https://moderndevice.com/product/current-sensor/) has some promise and is considerably more affordable.

I do appreciate all the suggestions.

Comment: 70 USD sounds like a bargain for this feature. If you can cut and split each power cable, you can get around this cheaper but far from as integrated.

Comment: Buy or make a short female to male extension cable and split that.

Comment: Assuming your power tools are motorized devices you could try placing a hall-effect sensor on/near the motor to detect the magnetic field produced when the motor runs.

Comment: You can also use resistive sensing. Detect the voltage drop across very small 1mOhm resistor when current flows. Just mind the safety and the fact AC crosses zero. Will require intercepting the line even more than a clamp but cheaper. You can always make short intercepting extensions cords or run all tools everything through one box to measure.

Comment: You can also purchase those devices for far less then $70 each. Amazon has listings for less than half that (and to those who're doubtless going to yell about UL listings - consider that the OP here as an admitted "electronics novice" is planning to build their own anyway...).

Comment: Add a current measuring (CT + Arduino or similar) device to the main power supply. Measure the general current and deduce what works. Draw the consequences for the dust removal control system.

Comment: yeah, this is omething I would consider adding to the breaker box.  run some circuits through a current transformer and plug the dust-making appliances into those circuits.

Comment: What kind of accuracy do you need? If you are only looking to see if its on or off, that gizmo will work. However, if you're looking for 3 digit accuracy, a solution going around both wire is very unlikely to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

the yellow device is some sort of magnetic field detector, as it can't go round only one of the conductors in the cable it must be operating just off what leaks out through the gaps.

is in there there will be a magnetic pick-up and, an amplifier, and probably some magnetic shielding.

The modern device board you found appears to contain the pickup and amplifier, and is probably the best way to proceed.